# What's the difference between RUN and bash script in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've seen many dockerfiles include all build steps in a RUN statement, like:

```
RUN echo "Hello" &&
    cd /tmp &&
    mv a.txt b.txt &&
    ...
    and so on...
```

My question is: what's the benefits/drawbacks on replace these instructions by a single bash script that gives me highlight syntax, loop capabilities, etc?
 Something like:

```
COPY ./script.sh /tmp
RUN  bash /tmp/script.sh
```

and then

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello" ;
cd /tmp ;
mv a.txt b.txt ;
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary difference is that when you `COPY` the bash script into the image it will be available for inspection in the running container, whereas the `RUN` command is a little more opaque.  Putting your commands in a file like that is arguably more manageable for other reasons: changes in your VCS history will be a little more clear, and for longer or more complex scripts you will probably find it easier to format things cleanly with the script in a separate file rather than embedded in your Dockerfile in a `RUN` command.

Otherwise the result is the same (in both cases, you are executing the same set of commands), although the `COPY` and `RUN` will result in an extra image layer (vs. just the `RUN` by itself).

Comment: Removing the script file after its execution may be a good practice, then... isn't it?

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion on that question. I would typically leave the script in place, but arguably it's already available in your sources, so...you know, whatever feels right :)

Comment: One last difference, `docker history` will not show the commands run inside of a shell script, only that you ran the script.

Answer (score 0):

I guess running it off as a `shell` script gives you more control.

For instance, you can do `if-else` statements to check whether a command has failed or not and provide a code path to handle it. Whereas `RUN` is more straight forward and when the return code is not `0` it fails the build immediately.

Obviously the case you have there is a relatively simple one and it would not have had a huge difference. The only impact I can see here is the code readability aspect. Someone would have to read the `shell script` to know what is happening, comparing to having everything on a single file.

I guess it all comes down to using the right tool for the right job. If it is a simple command and you don't need complex logic handling then do `RUN`.